# Why can't you reference modules that appear to be automatically loaded by the interpreter without an additional `import` statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

When you start your Python interpreter it appears that some modules/packages are automatically imported during the startup process:

```
python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jan 13 2014, 14:59:37)
...
>>> import sys
>>> for key in sys.modules.iterkeys():
...     print(key)
...
os
sys
abc
others ...
```

However, these modules seem to have been loaded into a different scope/namespace because you can't access them without an additional `import`:

```
>>> abc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'abc' is not defined
```

Here are my questions:

1. What precisely is loading these modules and for what purpose?
2. What scope/namespace were they loaded into?

Comment: You can't reference them automatically for the same reason that if you import `a` which imports `b`, you still can't refer to `b`. The fact that a module has been loaded doesn't mean it's assigned to a variable in every other module's namespace.

Comment: Thank you @user2357112, that makes sense, but what is responsible for loading them (since I didn't) and what namespace did it load them into?  Trying to understand the guts here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a fresh interpreter startup, [`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.modules) will contain those modules that were loaded automatically by Python because they perform roles necessary for the Python interpreter to run. For example, [`Py_InitializeEx`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3b6e0720a69d/Python/pythonrun.c#l140) in `Python/pythonrun.c` includes lines like

```
bimod = _PyBuiltin_Init();
```

which initializes the `__builtin__` module, where builtins like `int` and `open` live, and

```
sysmod = _PySys_Init();
```

which initializes the [`sys`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html) module.

As for what namespace these modules are loaded into, modules aren't really loaded into namespaces. The `import` statement loads a module and assigns the module or items from the module into a variable or variables in the current namespace, but the module loading and the assignment are independent steps. Calls like `_PySys_Init` don't assign the module into any particular namespace. However, the import machinery will record in [`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.modules) any module loaded by any code in the current Python execution, so further imports don't re-execute the module and create a new copy.

Answer (score 4):

the `sys` module is loading them into the `sys.modules` dictionary namespace

if you wanted to I guess you could access them as

```
abc = sys.modules["abc"]
```

but not sure why you would want to

Comment: This is kind of misleading. It implies that all those things were imported by `sys`, and that `sys` is responsible for putting them in `sys.modules`. Neither of those things is true.

Answer (score 3):

It includes all modules you ever imported so if you `del module` the module will still appear in the dict but it does not mean you can access it:

```
In [16]: import BeautifulSoup

In [17]: sys.modules["BeautifulSoup"]
Out[17]: <module 'BeautifulSoup' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/BeautifulSoup.pyc'>

In [18]: BeautifulSoup.re
Out[18]: <module 're' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/re.pyc'>

In [19]: del BeautifulSoup

In [20]: sys.modules["BeautifulSoup"]
Out[20]: <module 'BeautifulSoup' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/BeautifulSoup.pyc'>

In [21]: BeautifulSoup.re
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-db67e3f66def> in <module>()
----> 1 BeautifulSoup.re

NameError: name 'BeautifulSoup' is not defined
```

Python preloads some module on startup and any modules that are imported that also import other modules will mean the other modules can appear in sys.modules but are not accessible in your namespace:

```
In [1]: sys.modules["numpy"]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-88fb63c48e78> in <module>()
----> 1 sys.modules["numpy"]

KeyError: 'numpy'

In [2]: cat test.py

import numpy

In [3]: import test

In [4]: sys.modules["numpy"]
Out[4]: <module 'numpy' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc'>

In [5]: numpy.array
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-132169fc46d3> in <module>()
----> 1 numpy.array
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  That is indeed the behavior I would expect if I had previously imported modules, but in this case, I just started the interpreter and they were already in sys.modules.

Comment: @eikonomega, python preloads some modules on startup as does Ipython, if the imports are removed or imported from another module they will still appear but you won't be able to use them in your current namespace